# How to deploy the image from JFrog Artifactory into Azure Kubernetes service using Azure DevOps

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-aks, jfrog-container-registry, acr

I build and push docker image into JFrog Artifactory by using Azure DevOps build pipeline. And then using the below yaml file to deploy the image into Azure AKS environment using Kubectl task in the release definition.

```
--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: webapplication-jfrog-deployment
  name: webapplication-jfrog-deployment
spec: 
  replicas: 2
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: webapplication-jfrog
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: webapplication-jfrog
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - 
          image: #{JFrog_Login_Server_Name}#/webapplication:#{Version}#
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: webapplication-jfrog
          ports: 
            - 
              containerPort: 80
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: webapplication-jfrog-service
spec: 
  ports: 
    - 
      port: 80
  selector: 
    app: webapplication-jfrog
  type: LoadBalancer
```

After deploying the above yaml file, I am getting the below error in the pods:

> **Failed to pull image "xxxx-poc.jfrog.io/webapplication:xx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://xxxx-poc.jfrog.io/v2/webapplication/manifests/xx: unknown: Authentication is required**

This error occurred might be the authentication issue, while pulling the image from JFrog Artifactory into Azure AKS environment.

So, can anyone suggest me how to deploy the image from JFrog Artifactory into Azure Kubernetes service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any private registry, you need to create a `docker-registry` secret and specify that when pulling images using `imagePullSecrets`.

1. Create the secret

```bash
kubectl create secret docker-registry artifactorycred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

2. Specify the secret in pod definition

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: artifactorycred
```

See the following document for more details:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/